# Libgdx background and foreground in single stage

Tags: screen, libgdx, resolution

My requirements:

1. Background filling entire physical screen (stretching if required)
2. Preserve aspect ratio of foreground assets (Work with virtual width and height)

For this, I use two Stages in my Screen as shown in the code below.

```
public void render(float delta) {
    backgroundStage.act(delta);
    backgroundStage.draw();
    foregroundStage.act(delta);
    foregroundStage.draw();
    }

public void resize(int width, int height) {
    background.setWidth(width);
    background.setHeight(height);
    backgroundStage.setViewport(width, height, true);
    foregroundStage.setViewport(MainGame.WIDTH, MainGame.HEIGHT, true);
    foregroundStage.getCamera().position.set(-foregroundStage.getGutterWidth(),-foregroundStage.getGutterHeight(),0);
    }
```

In all the tutorials I have read, I have only seen one stage being used for each screen. So, how do I fulfill both the requirements in single stage? Is it too expensive to have separate stages? (I have read that SpriteBatch objects are heavy!)

**This is how I solved the problem:**

To get rid of background stage, I updated my render and resize functions as follows. Basically, I shifted the bottom right corner of background to (-gutterWidth,-gutterHeight) and added twice the values of gutter width and height to region width and height of the texture region. The stage is gone now :-)

```
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 1, 0, 0.5f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    foregroundStage.getSpriteBatch().begin();
    foregroundStage.getSpriteBatch().draw(backgroundImage,-gw,-gh,backgroundImage.getRegionWidth()+2*gw,backgroundImage.getRegionHeight()+2*gh);
    foregroundStage.getSpriteBatch().end();
    foregroundStage.act(delta);
    foregroundStage.draw();


public void resize(int width, int height) {
    screenW = width;
    screenH = height;
    foregroundStage.setViewport(MainGame.WIDTH, MainGame.HEIGHT, true);
    gw = foregroundStage.getGutterWidth();
    gh = foregroundStage.getGutterHeight();
    foregroundStage.getCamera().translate(-gw,-gh,0);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use two stages, but for your case it would be better to just solve this problem by creating two groups inside a single stage:

```
Stage stage = new Stage();

Group background = new Group();
background.setBounds(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
Group foreground = new Group();
foreground.setBounds(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

// Notice the order
stage.addActor(background);
stage.addActor(foreground);

foreground.addActor(new Actor());
// Or anything else you want to add like you normally would to the stage. 

background.addActor(new Image()); // your background image here.

Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```

Comment: Thanks. But I want different viewports for background and foreground as I have written in my code above. How do I achieve that without calculating the size for foreground by myself?

Comment: You can set the viewport to the foreground one, then resize bounds of the background image to match the size you want it to be. You could even render the image separate from the stage as a texture region which would allow you to render it however you like. There are a couple options, but there is no reason to use two stages to do that. Unless you plan to render a ton of stuff (in addition to your background image) in the background, then two stages might make more sense.

Comment: Yeah I did that. I added shifted the background to (-gutterWidth,-gutterHeight) and added twice the values of gutter width and height to region width and height of the texture region. The stage is gone now :-)