# libGDX : Draw texture as background for actors on stage when call stage contructor with batch

Tags: java, libgdx

In ScrollPaneStyle contructor calling the first parameter `(Drawable background, ...` . So, I can't draw texture in batch as background for it.

This Problem appears when I create stage with `batch`:

```
stage = new Stage(new StretchViewport(480, 800), batch);
```

If I call Stage constructor with viewport only (not with batch), the problem gone!

```
paneStyle = new ScrollPaneStyle(null, null, null, null, skin.getDrawable("knob"));
```

I put the first parameter `null` because I want to draw texture in batch as background for all actors (NOT background for scrollPane only)

How can I draw texture in batch as background for scrollPane and all actors on the stage ?

Comment: There is a two link that can help to figure that out: [Background image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22536755/libgdx-how-to-add-background-image-in-stage) and [How to work with two layers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18200669/libgdx-background-and-foreground-in-single-stage)

Comment: Thanx , I created two stages and my problem solved.