# Libgdx how to make rectangle texture either go to background or foreground...set layers?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm trying to figure out how to make a rectangle texture show up either behind or in front of another image. In this particular case it's an array rectangle behind a rectangle.

Also trying to figure out how to keep an "what is your score" string in front of all other textures.

Is there a way to specify a texture layer order in libgdx? I tried changing the order they are created and rendered in to no avail. Also couldn't find any info so maybe it's just called something else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Libgdx background and foreground in single stage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18200669/libgdx-background-and-foreground-in-single-stage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to draw the background textures first, then the foreground, then the score:

(semi-pseudo code, as I haven't done libgdx in a while)

```
 public void update(float _delta)
 {
     spritebatch.begin();
     drawbackgrounds();
     drawforegrounds();
     drawoverlay();
     spritebatch.end();
 }

 private void drawbackgrounds()
 {
     //draw your background textures here
 }

 private void drawforegrounds()
 {
     //draw your foreground textures here
 }

 private void drawbackgrounds()
 {
     //draw your overlay here
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Scene2D? If so, you can use [actor#toFront](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html#toFront--) or [actor#toBack](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html#toBack--)

If you are rendering using Batch & ShapeRenderer, then the order that you render them in is what their draw priority on the screen is.

So if you render a rectangle first and the score label second; the label will be shown.

However, if you render the label first and the rectangle second; the rectangle will take priority and draw on top of the label.

If you are using the OpenGL functions to create these displays, then I assume that the render order rule still applies.

Answer (score 0):

```
    batch.begin();
    ......something draw here as background
    batch.end();

    //stage start
    stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    stage.draw();

    batch_front.begin();
    ......something draw here as foreground
    batch_front.end();
```